# WCF Async Method call returns a response object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, asynchronous

I'm currently working on a WCF Service and a client consuming it. 
Until yesterday, the service was working perfectly. I could call the methods normally as well as async.
But: Then I added some new methods to the interface and the service class. Then I used svcutil.exe to generate the Service.cs and output.config for the client.
Now the async Methods aren't returning their return type anymore, but some "Task<[MethodName]Result>" type.

This is how my **IService.cs** looks like:

```
public interface IService{
[OperationContract]
string GetData(int value);

[OperationContract]
LoginResultSet TryUserLogin(int clientID, string inputValue);

[OperationContract]
LoginResultSet TryClientLogin(string computerName);

[OperationContract]
bool IsClientLoggedIn(int clientID);

[OperationContract]
LoginResultSet TryClientLogout(int clientID);

[OperationContract]
LoginResultSet TryUserLogout(int clientID, UserClass user);

[OperationContract]
DataTable GetTestJU(int index);

[OperationContract]
DataTable GetJUHistory(UserClass user, int maxCount);

[OperationContract]
DataTable GetJU(UserClass user, string inputValue);}
```

The problem starts already at the login. In the **previous** version of my generated Service.cs the **TryUserLogin** and **TryUserLoginAsync** methods looked like this:

```
 public LoginResultSet TryUserLogin(int ClientID, string InputValue)
{
    return base.Channel.TryUserLogin(ClientID, InputValue);
}

public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<LoginResultSet> TryUserLoginAsync(int ClientID, string InputValue)
{
    return base.Channel.TryUserLoginAsync(ClientID, InputValue);
}
```

which was perfectly working.

But in the new **Service.cs** I get this:

```
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
TryUserLoginResponse IService.TryUserLogin(TryUserLoginRequest request)
{
    return base.Channel.TryUserLogin(request);
}

public LoginResultSet TryUserLogin(int clientID, string inputValue)
{
    TryUserLoginRequest inValue = new TryUserLoginRequest();
    inValue.clientID = clientID;
    inValue.inputValue = inputValue;
    TryUserLoginResponse retVal = ((IService)(this)).TryUserLogin(inValue);
    return retVal.TryUserLoginResult;
}

[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TryUserLoginResponse> IService.TryUserLoginAsync(TryUserLoginRequest request)
{
    return base.Channel.TryUserLoginAsync(request);
}

public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TryUserLoginResponse> TryUserLoginAsync(int clientID, string inputValue)
{
    TryUserLoginRequest inValue = new TryUserLoginRequest();
    inValue.clientID = clientID;
    inValue.inputValue = inputValue;
    return ((IService)(this)).TryUserLoginAsync(inValue);
}
```

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong. I noticed that in the new Service.cs the attributes in front of the methods are always from the `System.ComponentModel` namespace whereas in the old (working) one, there attributes were from the `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace and there were way less of those attributes.

I really hope somebody can help, I'm kind of desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea why there is that problem with the return value, but I'm avoiding the problem by building my own task and using the "normal" login method, like this:

```
LoginResultSet result = new LoginResultSet();
Task<LoginResultSet> loginTask = new Task<LoginResultSet>(() =>
{
    return WCFClient.TryClientLogin(Environment.MachineName);
});
loginTask.Start();
await Task.WhenAll(loginTask);

result = loginTask.Result;
```

Nevertheless I would be really interested in a solution for fixing the generated file.